# How to display a dict context in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How do you display a dict context passed to a template in Django?  I tried these but I got errors and a blank respectively.

```
showdict.html 

{{ mydict['key1']['key2'] }}
{{ mydict.key1.key2 }}  

views.py

mydict = getDict()

return render(request, 'showdict.html', {'mydict': mydict, })
```

Comment: The second one is correct, as is clearly documented. If it's not working you'll need to give more information, such as where mydict is defined.

Comment: mydict is defined in views.py passed through render as a context.

Comment: How? *Show the code*.

Comment: If key1 and key2 are variables you'll need a custom template tag. I had the same issue.